# Why am I getting " java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple socket to my loopback address -

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4424);
```

when i get this exception. How do i resolve it?

Comment: Please define ur ques. in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Have you a socket server listening on port 4424?

You are creating a socket client. It can communicate only with a running socket server on the same port.

If you like you can create a server in java using the `ServerSocket` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket server is not listening to localhost.Make sure that u have socket server on ur machine nd if not please download it .